# PayPal Adaptive Payment Permission

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I read the documentation from PayPal and there is one section stated that

"You can use the following standard services without requesting specific permission:

- Making simple or parallel payments that require explicit approval of 
  the sender
- Getting payment details
- Making refunds
- Performing currency conversions

To use any other service, **you must receive permission from PayPal** to use the service when you submit your application."

Does it mean that if I want to use Adaptive Chained Payment I need to ask for special permission from PayPal ? if so how would I submit the request ? Is there any possible obstacle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply for an APP ID regardless.  The services listed above may be quickly approved, whereas other services may require more information.

To apply for a live Adaptive Payments APP ID, go to https://developer.paypal.com -> Applications -> My apps -> Create and manage Classic API apps.